# i want to check the network state but it give me nullPointerException why?

Tags: java, android

I am receiving a `NullPointerException` with the code below. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```
public void clickMe(View v) //the view is button
    {   

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        String b;

        if(networkInfo.isConnected())
            b="on";
        else
            b="off";

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, b , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: On what line is the NullPointerException thrown?  Please post a stack trace.

Comment: at ( if(networkInfo.isConnected()) )

Comment: how to get the stack trace at eclipse ?

Comment: First, please read my answer. Second, the LogCat should automatically open when the app crashes, then highlight and copy the red lines into your question.

Comment: there is no enough space at comments to post the stack trace

Comment: Click "[edit]" below your question to add it to the question itself. (In the future, if your app crashes always post the stack trace.)

Comment: @Sam you are right i have to check if networkInfo is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`getActiveNetworkInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)'s documentation:

> Returns details about the currently active data network. When connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections. You should always check `isConnected()` before initiating network traffic. This may return `null` when no networks are available.

So you don't have any active networks, check if it's `null` like so:

```
if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

> This method requires the caller to hold the permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

You need to add this permission to your app if you haven't. If you don't, you may get no results and unexpectedly get a null result.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Make sure that's added in your manifest.

Comment: Will this throw an NullPointerException?

Comment: Yes, it will. You're required to have it. I've added a link and a statement from the documentation.

Comment: Are you sure? This has nothing to do with NPEs, this will throw a SecurityException...

Comment: It's in the documentation. It specifically says the method you are calling requires it. Please try it and see

Comment: I have, have you? (Shall I post the stack trace?) The author clearly states the problem is with a NPE, so this answer is irrelevant. That is why I left it out of my answer. (Sorry)

Comment: but i have the permission already

Comment: @MA5 Have you checked if `networkInfo` is `null`?

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was replying to the OP didn't notice it was someone else. I was under the impression is would simply return null in either case, missing security or no network found.

Comment: @Sam you are right i have to check if networkInfo is null